# Connection timed out for OpenVPN

Tags: vpn

I'm using Ubuntu Xenial. I am trying to setup my VPN by following this:

https://hide.me/en/vpnsetup/ubuntu/openvpn/

However, when I `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` I see

```
Aug 26 22:59:07 me nm-openvpn[4733]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
Aug 26 22:59:07 me nm-openvpn[4733]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Aug 26 22:59:19 me nm-openvpn[4733]: WARNING: --ping should normally be used with --ping-restart or --ping-exit
Aug 26 22:59:19 me nm-openvpn[4733]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Aug 26 22:59:19 me nm-openvpn[4733]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]43.249.37.33:443 [nonblock]
Aug 26 22:59:20 me nm-openvpn[4733]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]43.249.37.33:443
Aug 26 22:59:20 me nm-openvpn[4733]: TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Aug 26 22:59:20 me nm-openvpn[4733]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]43.249.37.33:443
Aug 26 22:59:21 me nm-openvpn[4733]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
Aug 26 22:59:21 me nm-openvpn[4733]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Aug 26 22:59:26 me nm-openvpn[47

Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: <warn>  [1503795586.3960] vpn-connection[0x19c11f0,1202a72d-ffe5-465c-920d-1f60cf673bf1,"hk5.nordvpn.com.tcp443",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: libnm-Message: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[4733]: send SIGTERM
Aug 27 22:59:46 me nm-openvpn[4733]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[4733] exited with success
Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: <warn>  [1503795586.4002] vpn-connection[0x19c11f0,1202a72d-ffe5-465c-920d-1f60cf673bf1,"hk5.nordvpn.com.tcp443",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: <info>  [1503795586.4002] vpn-connection[0x19c11f0,1202a72d-ffe5-465c-920d-1f60cf673bf1,"hk5.nordvpn.com.tcp443",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Aug 27 22:59:46 me NetworkManager[773]: <info>  [1503795586.4003] vpn-connection[0x19c11f0,1202a72d-ffe5-465c-920d-1f60cf673bf1,"hk5.nordvpn.com.tcp443",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Aug 27 23:00:01 me systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 27 23:00:01 me systemd[1]: Stopped Bumblebee C Daemon.
Aug 27 23:00:01 me systemd[1]: Started Bumblebee C Daemon.
Aug 27 23:00:01 me bumblebeed[4818]: [ 1147.846303] [ERROR]No discrete video card found, quitting
Aug 27 23:00:01 me systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: what version of ubuntu is this?